# Trac - Problems upgrading from 0.12.5 to 1.0.1

Tags: debian, trac

I've been trying to upgrade our trac environment from 0.12.5 to 1.0.1 on debian squeeze. I updated it using wheezy backports.

After I installed the new version using apt-get I ran the following:

```
trac-admin /var/lib/trac upgrade
trac-admin /var/lib/trac wiki upgrade
```

When I opened trac in my browser I got the following errors:

```
    Trac[env] WARNING: base_url option not set in configuration, generated links may be incorrect
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "trac.wiki.admin = trac.wiki.admin": (can't import "ImportError: No module named admin")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "tracopt.ticket.commit_updater = tracopt.ticket.commit_updater": (can't import "ImportError: cannot import name cleandoc_")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.svn_fs = tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.svn_fs": (can't import "ImportError: cannot import name ChoiceOption")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "tracopt.ticket.clone = tracopt.ticket.clone": (can't import "ImportError: cannot import name captioned_button")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "tracopt.ticket.deleter = tracopt.ticket.deleter": (can't import "ImportError: cannot import name from_utimestamp")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "trac.wiki.web_api = trac.wiki.web_api": (can't import "ImportError: No module named web_api")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "trac.versioncontrol.admin = trac.versioncontrol.admin": (can't import "ImportError: No module named admin")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "trac.ticket.batch = trac.ticket.batch": (can't import "ImportError: No module named batch")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider = tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider": (can't import "ImportError: cannot import name ConfigSection")
Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin from /var/lib/trac/plugins/setup.py: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/loader.py", line 91, in _load_py_files
```

As I can see I have the following plugins installed if it helps:

TracHierWiki

TracXMLRPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, the line

> Failed to load plugin from /var/lib/trac/plugins/setup.py

means, that there is not properly packaged multi-file Trac plugin source code (`setup.py` file) in the `/plugin` directory of your Trac environment, that must not be there.

This situation has been recently discussed in Trac ticket [#11846](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11846) for a solution in upstream Trac development.

Comment: Nice catch! I looked at the traceback yesterday and didn't see it. Potentially gives more weight to fixing [#11846](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11846), particularly given the frequency in which similar issues have been occurring. Also, improved user education on what belongs in `$env/plugins` could be important.

Comment: Thank you! We had some old plugins and files under the plugin folder. Removed everything except the newest plugin which ended with .egg and everything worked fine!